# Segmentation fault due to string copy

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

In the code below the code crashes after executing while loop for 4th time, and it crashes in strcpy

```
strcpy(userver_info[location].Tag_Name, field);
```

When debugging it gave following error

```
Can't find a source file at "strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S"
```

I am not able to figureout what is the issue which is causing crash here, after facing the above issue i did structure padding thinking that may be the issue and even that is not working out, can anyone  please tell me why is the code crashing.

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
>
> #define BUFFER_SIZE               1024
> #define NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER  0
>
>
> #define SHM_ADDR_LEN              15
> #define SERVER_NAME_LEN           25
> #define TAG_NAME_LEN              25
> #define TAG_DESC_LEN              30
> #define ACCESS_LEVEL_LEN          5
> #define DATA_TYPE_NAME_LEN            10
>
> typedef struct {
>   char    SHM_Location[SHM_ADDR_LEN];
>   char    Server_ID[SERVER_NAME_LEN];
>   char    Tag_Name[TAG_NAME_LEN];
>   int     Tag_ID;
>   char    Tag_Description[TAG_DESC_LEN];
>   char    Access_Level[ACCESS_LEVEL_LEN];
>   char    Data_Type[DATA_TYPE_NAME_LEN];
> }u_server_info;
>
> typedef struct {
>   int num_of_tags;
>   u_server_info *underlying_server_data;
> }opcua_u_server;
>
>
>
> void parse_underlying_opcua_server(char * buffer, u_server_info *userver_info) {
>
>   static int location = 0;
>   char *field;
>   /* get SHM_Location */
>   field = strtok(buffer,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].SHM_Location, field);
>
>   /* get Server_ID */
>   field=strtok(NULL,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].Server_ID, field);
>
>   /* get Tag_Name */
>   field = strtok(NULL,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].Tag_Name, field);
>
>   /* get Tag_ID */
>   field=strtok(NULL,",");
>   userver_info[location].Tag_ID = atoi(field);
>
>   /* get Tag_Description */
>   field = strtok(NULL,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].Tag_Description, field);
>
>   /* get Access_Level */
>   field = strtok(NULL,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].Access_Level, field);
>
>   /* get Data_Type */
>   field = strtok(NULL,",");
>   strcpy(userver_info[location].Data_Type, field);
>
>   /* display the result */
>   printf("%s\t %s\t %s\t %d\t %s\t %s\t %s\n",
>           userver_info[location].SHM_Location,
>           userver_info[location].Server_ID,
>           userver_info[location].Tag_Name,
>           userver_info[location].Tag_ID,
>           userver_info[location].Tag_Description,
>           userver_info[location].Access_Level,
>           userver_info[location].Data_Type);
>
>   location++;
> }
>
>
> int get_line_count(char *filename) {
>
>   FILE *fp;
>   int line_count = 0;
>   char c;
>   fp = fopen(filename, "r");
>   if (fp == NULL){
>       printf("Unable to open file '%s' to count lines\n",filename);
>       return -1;
>   }
>   for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
>       if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
>           line_count = line_count + 1;
>   fclose(fp);
>   return line_count;
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>   char filename[] = "underlying_server.csv";
>   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
>   FILE *fp;
>   int tags_count = 0;
>   opcua_u_server *ua_server = NULL;
>
>   /* open the CSV file */
>   fp = fopen(filename,"r");
>   if( fp == NULL) {
>       printf("Unable to open file '%s'\n",filename);
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }
>
>   tags_count = get_line_count(filename);
>   /* Allocate memmory for each Underlying server */
>   ua_server= malloc(sizeof(opcua_u_server));
>   if (ua_server == NULL) {
>       printf("Malloc failed");
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }
>   /* Allocate memory for each underlying server tag information */
>   ua_server[NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER].underlying_server_data =
>           malloc(tags_count * sizeof(ua_server->underlying_server_data));
>
>   if (ua_server[NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER].underlying_server_data == NULL) {
>       printf("Malloc failed");
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }
>   /* process the data */
>   while(fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,fp)) {
>
>       parse_underlying_opcua_server(buffer,
>                       ua_server[NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER].underlying_server_data);
>
>   }
>   ua_server->num_of_tags = tags_count;
>   /*Reset the value for next server*/
>   tags_count = 0;
>   /* close file */
>   fclose(fp);
>
>   return(0);
> }
> ```

My underlying_server.csv is like this

> ```
> 1000,Server_1,Tag_1,3000,Created_tag_3000,AR,BOOL
> 1001,Server_1,Tag_2,3001,Created_tag_3001,AR,BOOL
> 1002,Server_1,Tag_3,3002,Created_tag_3002,AR,BOOL
> 1003,Server_1,Tag_4,3003,Created_tag_3003,AR,BOOL
> 1004,Server_1,Tag_5,3004,Created_tag_3004,AR,REAL
> 1005,Server_1,Tag_6,3005,Created_tag_3005,AR,REAL
> 1006,Server_1,Tag_7,3006,Created_tag_3006,AW,REAL
> 1007,Server_1,Tag_8,3007,Created_tag_3007,AW,REAL
> 1008,Server_1,Tag_9,3008,Created_tag_3008,AW,REAL
> 1009,Server_1,Tag_10,3009,Created_tag_3009,AW,REAL
> 1010,Server_1,Tag_11,3010,Created_tag_3010,AW,REAL
> 1011,Server_1,Tag_12,3011,Created_tag_3011,AW,DWORD
> 1012,Server_1,Tag_13,3012,Created_tag_3012,AW,DWORD
> 1013,Server_1,Tag_14,3013,Created_tag_3013,AR,DWORD
> 1014,Server_1,Tag_15,3014,Created_tag_3014,AR,DWORD
> 1015,Server_1,Tag_16,3015,Created_tag_3015,AR,DWORD
> 1016,Server_1,Tag_17,3016,Created_tag_3016,AR,DWORD
> 1017,Server_1,Tag_18,3017,Created_tag_3017,AR,DWORD
> 1018,Server_1,Tag_19,3018,Created_tag_3018,AR,DWORD
> 1019,Server_1,Tag_20,3019,Created_tag_3019,AR,DWORD
> 1020,Server_1,Tag_21,3020,Created_tag_3020,AR,DWORD
> 1021,Server_1,Tag_22,3021,Created_tag_3021,AW,BOOL
> 1022,Server_1,Tag_23,3022,Created_tag_3022,AW,BOOL
> 1023,Server_1,Tag_24,3023,Created_tag_3023,AW,BOOL
> 1024,Server_1,Tag_25,3024,Created_tag_3024,AW,BOOL
> 1025,Server_1,Tag_26,3025,Created_tag_3025,AW,BOOL
> 1026,Server_1,Tag_27,3026,Created_tag_3026,AW,DWORD
> 1027,Server_1,Tag_28,3027,Created_tag_3027,AR,DWORD
> 1028,Server_1,Tag_29,3028,Created_tag_3028,AR,DWORD
> 1029,Server_1,Tag_30,3029,Created_tag_3029,AR,DWORD
> 1030,Server_1,Tag_31,3030,Created_tag_3030,AR,REAL
> ```

Comment: That looks like way too much code; can you reduce it further to a [mcve]?

Comment: Start with `char c;` -> `int c;` for `for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))`. `getc` returns an `int`.

Comment: For starters, check if the `field` values up to and including that point are all what you expect - in particular, if `strtok` just returned a null pointer, that's bad news.

Comment: Your malloc code doesn't make any sense. In addition to being completely wrong, you should be [correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) anyway.

Comment: @Angew This is fine, the bug was easy to spot in a few minutes of untangling what `userver_info` was. Just need a bit of text search to do that, so it doesn't matter if this is 100 LoC or 100k LoC.

Comment: @Angew What the OP posted looks like a MCVE to me. Maybe not 100% minimal, but other than that, it's fine.

Comment: @NikosC. Yeah, the "Minimal" part is what I was after. Note that I neither DVed nor VTCed, it just looked like an unnecessary wall of code to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there is a dup for this, you are allocating the second buffer based on the  sizeof the pointer, not the object being pointed to:

```
/* Allocate memory for each underlying server tag information */
ua_server[NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER].underlying_server_data =
      malloc(tags_count * sizeof(ua_server->underlying_server_data));
```

becomes:

```
/* Allocate memory for each underlying server tag information */
ua_server[NUM_OF_UNDERLYING_SERVER].underlying_server_data =
      malloc(tags_count * sizeof(*(ua_server->underlying_server_data)));
```

Note the actual code `*(ua_server->underlying_server_data` is bad at this moment, but sizeof is compile-time and is just using the code as a template to get the object size.

I sometimes wish there was a compiler warning for "You asked for the sizeof a pointer"

Comment: You can just write `sizeof(*ua_server->underlying_server_data)`. You don't need the parentheses.

Comment: `ua_server= malloc(sizeof(opcua_u_server));` is also broken because it only allocates a single object, but the code then uses it as an array of pointers, which it is not. All malloc lines in the code are wrong.

Comment: You can just write sizeof *ua_server->underlying_server_data. You don't need the parentheses.

Comment: @dmur you can, but personally I find it clearer with the brackets when I switch association sides.

Answer (score -5):

Never use `strcpy`, it's insecure, because it doesn't perform any form of bounds constraining and will just soldier on copying until it hits a 0 byte in the source buffer. If the source buffer isn't (properly) 0-terminated, or the contents of the source buffer are too long to fit into the destination, it will create undefined behavior (crash or be vulnerable to attack).

Putting aside the problem with fixed size fields, it is absolutely necessary to check the size limits of buffer operations. The standard function you'd use (although it still isn't perfect) is `strncpy` (note the extra `n`). The caveat is, that `strncpy` will omit the terminating 0 byte if it doesn't fit into the destination.

Since your fields are fixed size you can use it like this

```
strncpy(userver_info[location].SHM_Location, field, SHM_ADDR_LEN-1);
userver_info[location].SHM_Location[SHM_ADDR_LEN-1] = 0;
```

i.e. it copies up to `SHM_ADDR_LEN-1` bytes and will always put a terminating 0 at the very end of the buffer.